# How to prevent page refresh during user input validation? Using form.onsubmit

Tags: javascript

My HTML page contains a `form` that has two sections for entering text (`section1` and `section2`) . Because I want to validate user input in each section separately, I created `function1` for validating `section1` and `function2` for validating `section2`:

```
var formIsValid = true; // global flag-variable to indicate form is valid

function function1() {
   if (at least one field in section 1 has bad data) {
      formIsValid = false;
      return false;
   }
   else {
      formIsValid = true;
      return true;
   }
}

// function2 is identical, except that it validates section2
// unlike section1, section 2 only has one input field
```

The idea is that once the user clicks `submit` button, the browser will first validate `section1`, and if the user data is valid, proceed to validating `section2`. If at some point, the data in one of the `field`s is bad, then the browser will `alert` the user and let him enter new values for missing/invalid `field`s.

Here's my code to do it:

```
function beginTest() {
   document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
      function1();
      if (formIsValid == false) {
         function1();
         return false; // supposed to prevent refreshing, but it does not
      }
      function2();
      if (formIsValid == false) {
         function2();
         return false; // again, problem with automatic page reloading
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that whenever an invalid value is detected, ***the whole page is refreshed and the user has to enter every piece of data over again***. My goal is to validate the page with no refreshes. In other words, whatever values entered in `input` fields in either section MUST remain there if they have been successfully validated.

Q: How do I prevent the browser from refreshing the page during validation?

Please, pure JavaScript only, no JQuery. Thank you!

Comment: it works for me on Fire Fox And IE 11,May be there is exception in function1 or function2 that prevent execution from returning false, and please remove "else" statment from function1

Comment: @Alex Can you share the HTML code too in Fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `event.preventDefault();`.

Example:

```
function beginTest() {
   document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(event) {
      function1();
      if (formIsValid == false) {
         function1();
         event.preventDefault();
         return false; // supposed to prevent refreshing, but it does not
      }
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is

```
window.onUnload = function() {var l = confirm("are u sure u want to leave");return l;}
```

This triggers when the page is about to unload and move to another page.